# loop list as if last element precedes first

Tags: python

If I have n elements in a list, I want start with the first element and slice the next x elements for the entire list such that it treats the last element in the list as if it precedes the first.

Example:

if I want slices of 5 elements each and my list is:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I want the output to be for each slice:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a']

['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b']

['e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']

['f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

This is my current code:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

i = 1
j = 6

while i <len(l):
    print(l[i:j], end = " ")
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

My current output is:

```
['b','c','d','e','f']

['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

['d', 'e', 'f']

['e', 'f']

['f']
```

Comment: you don't want the first result to start with 'a'?

Comment: Not for what I'm doing, no. But I'm assuming if I had a use case come up like that then I could adjust accordingly relatively easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use modulo

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
i = 1
j = 6

n=len(l)
while i <=len(l):
    k=i
    for k in range (i,j):
        print(l[k%n], end = " ")
    print()
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

output:

```
b c d e f 
c d e f a 
d e f a b 
e f a b c 
f a b c d 
a b c d e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for i, _ in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[i+1:] + lst[:i])
```

In your code, when list index goes out of range (after you increment `j`) it essentially does nothing and is same as `lst[i:]`

Comment: This works for the list in question, but it didn't behave as expected on a list of a different size (of 100 elements in the other case I tried).

Comment: list size should be irrelevant. What behaviour are you getting?

Comment: I only want 5 elements per slice (or whatever number per slice that I decide). This seems to give me back more than 5 when I used a larger list.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your slicing work by doubling the list ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxJCoAwDAXQfU4RunLaqCAiehJx4VAxpdSiBfH0NTGLx@eTxL/hOF3d@itGewcccFSzKlAtwipsghZ2NQEQ75Rg2AYsK1cZVgDPQVYjYc@ddgn3aQfI4y9yIbEjdWZK/4YwlycSzR9j/AA)):

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

i = 1
j = 6
l = lst * 2

while i <= len(lst):
    print(l[i:j])
    i += 1
    j += 1
```

Another way ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P6e4RMFWIVopUUlHQSkJRCSDiBQQkQoi0pRiubjS8osU4hUy8xSAyq24FICgAqgLyNEryC/QMNAECxUUZeaVaAAFIVyQbGJBQWpeikaF5v//AA)):

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for _ in lst:
    x = lst.pop(0)
    print(lst)
    lst.append(x)
```

Comment: These two methods appear to behave differently depending on the size of the list.

Comment: @J.Sakovich "behave differently" how?

Comment: The first method returns 5 elements per on a list of 100. The second method is giving me 99.

Comment: @J.Sakovich Well,  yes, I kept your hard coded 6 because I tried to fix your code with as little modifications as possible. With `j = len(lst)` it prints 99 as well.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me learn some new stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You could just "rotate" the list:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s = 5  # size of slices
n = 6  # number of slices
for _ in range(n):
    lst.append(lst.pop(0))
    print(lst[:s])
```

Or use a Deque, just for fun:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
q = deque(lst)
s = 5  # size of slices
n = 6  # number of slices
for _ in range(n):
    q.rotate(-1)
    print(list(islice(q, 0, s)))
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't learned about Deques before - that's super cool! Thank you for sharing!